# Why does React does not include shadow DOM? Would it not make the life a lot easier than working with CSS in JS solutions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles, shadow-dom, virtual-dom

What are the reasons react does not support shadow dom internally. Currently to solve style encapsulation issues we need to use 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Shadow DOM is implemented only in last releases of modern browsers (Chrome, Opera and Firefox only).

While the React team has developed a solution for much more browsers and older releases.

Moreover the switch to Shadow DOM would imply a lot of changes in the framework architecture and philosofy (with no retro-compatibility).

Last I suppose the team is happy with its current virtual DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual DOM is faster beacause avoid unnecessary changes to the DOM, which are expensive performance-wise, because changes to the DOM usually cause re-rendering of the page, also it allows to collect several changes to be applied at once, so not every single change causes a re-render, but instead re-rendering only happens once after a set of changes was applied to the DOM.

If you feel the need to implement shadow DOM in react, here we are:

https://github.com/Wildhoney/ReactShadow

Comment: Thanks, but what I wanna know is, why reactjs folks didn't add shadow dom with virtual dom

Comment: React along with standard css management (sass, less etct) support and promote state based mutation of render (and styles) with virtual dom reconciliation of the render. There is no situation I can think about that needs to be solved with shadow dom encapsulation.